# Best file format regarding standard string and integer data?

Tags: java, file-format

For my project, I need to store info about protocols (the data sent (most likely integers) and in the order it's sent) and info that might be formatted something like this:
**'ID' 'STRING' 'ADDITIONAL INTEGER DATA'**
This info will be read by a Java program and stored in memory for processing, but I don't know what would be the most sensible format to store this data in?

EDIT: Here's some extra information:
1)I will be using this data in a game server.
2)Since it is a game server, speed is not the primary concern, since this data will primary be read and utilized during startup, which shouldn't occur very often. 
3)Memory consumption I would like to keep at a minimum, however.
4)The second data "example" will be used as a "dictionary" to look up names of specific in-game items, their stats and other integer data (and therefore might become very large, unlike the first data containing the protocol information, where each file will only note small protocol bites, like a login protocol for instance).
5)And yes, I would like the data to be "human-editable".

EDIT 2: Here's the choices that I've made:
[JSON](http://www.json.org/) - For the protocol descriptions
[CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) - For the dictionaries

Comment: Can you give an example of 'Additional Integer data'?  Is it one integer, a list of integers, a specified format of integers or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many factors that could come to weigh--here are things that might help you figure this out:

1) Speed/memory usage:  If the data needs to load very quickly or is very large, you'll probably want to consider rolling your own binary format.

2) Portability/compatibility:  Balanced against #1 is the consideration that you might want to use the data elsewhere, with programs that won't read a custom binary format. In this case, your heavy hitters are probably going to be CSV, dBase, XML, and my personal favorite, JSON.

3) Simplicity: Delimited formats like CSV are easy to read, write, and edit by hand. Either use double-quoting with proper escaping or choose a delimiter that will not appear in the data.

If you could post more info about your situation and how important these factors are, we might be able to guide you further.

Comment: Two more considerations:  Is the data heirarichal (looks like not in this case) and does it need to be human readable/writable?  If the last you can add YAML (http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/) to the list.

Answer (score 0):

How about XML, [JSON](http://www.json.org/)  or [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) ?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a similar protocol-specification using XML. (Available [here](http://multri.net/about/protocol.xml).)

I think it is a good match, since it captures the hierarchal nature of specifying messages / network packages / fields etc. Order of fields are well defined and so on.

I even wrote a code-generator that generated the message sending / receiving classes with methods for each message type in XSLT.

The only drawback as I see it is the verbosity. If you have a really simple structure of the specification, I would suggest you use some simple home-brewed format and write a parser for it using a parser-generator of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the formats suggested by others here (CSV, XML, JSON, etc.) you might consider storing the info in a Java properties file. (See the [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) class.) The code is already there for you, so all you have to figure out is the properties names (or name prefixes) you want to use.

The `Properties` class also provides for storing/loading properties in a simple XML format.